# Objective C programmatical binding doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, binding

An imageView is properly bound as IBOutlet ("imageOKData"). I have programmatically bound its visibility (hidden) to a BOOL property of a custom object that already is available when creating the binding.

in `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"Create binding: %hhd",_global.dataFile.imported);    
// --> "Create binding: 0"  

NSDictionary* reverseBool = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption,NSNegateBooleanTransformerName,
                         nil];  

[_imageOKData bind:@"hidden" toObject:_global.dataFile withKeyPath:@"imported" options:reverseBool];    

}
```

With the above code the image should be hidden once the `viewDidLoad`. But its still visible. Even if i remove the `reverseBool` options it' still there. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the options dictionary. Jeeeez... i've mistaken the order. It must be

```
NSDictionary* reverseBool = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSNegateBooleanTransformerName, NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption,nil];
```

Sometimes you don't see the hand in front of your face.